# image resize on node.js

Tags: node.js, image, resize, sharp

I want to save images after resize so used sharp package but dont small image size.Iadded   await sharp(uploadImage.name).resize(600, 600); line after save folder What am I missing?

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const AdminBro = require('admin-bro');
const sharp=require('sharp');

/** @type {AdminBro.After<AdminBro.ActionResponse>} */
const after = async (response, request, context) => {
  const { record, uploadImage } = context;

  if (record.isValid() && uploadImage) {
   // console.log(uploadImage.name);
   await sharp(uploadImage.name).resize(600, 600);
 
    const filePath = path.join('uploads', record.id().toString(), uploadImage.name);
    await fs.promises.mkdir(path.dirname(filePath), { recursive: true });

    await fs.promises.rename(uploadImage.path, filePath);

    await record.update({ imagePath: `/${filePath}` });
  }
  return response;
};

/** @type {AdminBro.Before} */
const before = async (request, context) => {
  if (request.method === 'post') {
    const { uploadImage, ...otherParams } = request.payload;

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    context.uploadImage = uploadImage;

    return {
      ...request,
      payload: otherParams,
    };
  }
  return request;
};

module.exports = { after, before };
```

---

```
const filePath = path.join('uploads', record.id().toString(), uploadImage.name); 
    await fs.promises.mkdir(path.dirname(filePath), { recursive: true });
    await sharp(uploadImage.path).withMetadata().resize(600,600).toFile(filePath);//here added correct paths but now although it saved image, doesnt reduce imageSize
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not writing the processed image to a file.

Let's say this is your storage path:

```
const outputPath = __dirname + `/../storage/myImage.jpeg`;
```

You can give that path to `sharp`

```
await sharp('path/of/originalImage').withMetadata().resize(600, 600).toFile(outputPath);
```

And I highly recommend you to use `withMetaData()` otherwise you lose your images metaData

Comment: is it same variable in sharp() and toFile()?

Comment: No, `path` is path of the resource image (Original image)

Comment: await fs.promises.mkdir(path.dirname(filePath), { recursive: true });
    await sharp(uploadImage.path).withMetadata().resize(600,600).toFile(filePath);
    console.log(uploadImage);
    await fs.promises.rename(uploadImage.path, filePath);

    await record.update({ imagePath: `/${filePath}` });        like this neither the program  give me error  nor reduce imageSize

Comment: I couldn't understand the problem. Can you add that part to your question, please?

Comment: But you are not specifying any file extension. What's the extension of the processed image? Can you try to add `.jpeg` end of the `filepath`?

Comment: If I use  an image that in 'Uploads' folder, work succesfully and reduce imageSize but  after I add image on adminPanel  they save in tmp folder first and they paths like =>/tmp/upload_d3a66b995350b442145f61c5cb3fc05b  dont have image extension

Comment: How do you save images to 'adminPanel'? Do you have discord or any other platform to speak? It's hard to communicate like this

Comment: if you use telegram we can speak thanks username:elifozz